# Disconnecting Netextender VPN: No internet

Tags: networking, vpn

I have had some problems with my internet connection.
After installing SonicWall NetExtender and connecting to my Office VPN and disconnecting again, I do not have internet access.

I can ping 8.8.8.8 and other IP-adresses. S it actually just seems to be a DNS problem.
When I connect to Netextender VPN again (this time I have to use IP-adress), I can browse via VPN again...

I have tried to uninstall NetExtender but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Open `/etc/resolv.conf` - where netExtender puts your office DNS entries. Delete them and put your prior DNS entry in.

I really would like to know how to force netExtenderGui to clean `resolv.conf`.

Comment: Yeah, that was also what i found out. It is quite strange why it does not clean up after itself...

Answer (score 5):

It is better to use the " --dns-only-local" option. 
This way Netextender won't update the /etc/resolv.conf file.

Answer (score 2):

It does clean up after itself.  The problem is that `resolv.conf` is a symlink.  NetExtender backs up the file and restores it but changes it from a symlink to a real file.  The rest of the software is updating what the symlink points to.